# A value of type 'ValueListenable<bool>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ValueNotifier<bool>'

Tags: flutter

## Error at plugin simple_animations:

```
/C:/Users/Abdo/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/simple_animations-4.2.0/lib/anicoto/animation_mixin.dart:139:56: Error: A value of type 'ValueListenable<bool>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ValueNotifier<bool>'.
 - 'ValueListenable' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart' ('/E:/SDKFlutter/3.13.2/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart').
 - 'ValueNotifier' is from 'package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart' ('/E:/SDKFlutter/3.13.2/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart').
    final ValueNotifier<bool> newNotifier = TickerMode.getNotifier(context);
```

## Problem Happened When update to flutter 3.13.2 version

Answer (score 2):

#fix simple_animations

### Error:

#### A value of type 'ValueListenable' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'ValueNotifier'.

## override the plugin version

```
dependency_overrides:
 
  simple_animations: ^5.0.2
```

## Cause by plugin awesome_dialog

### to fix this issue

```
dependency:
  awesome_dialog: ^3.1.0
  simple_animations: ^5.0.2

dependency_overrides:
  simple_animations: ^5.0.2
```